# Datatable to Excel Interop VS other approaches; required popup with Save As / Open

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, office-interop, export-to-excel

I've implemented the following approach that seems to be working just fine however it saves the file into pre-defined location, instead I'd like it to give an option to the user, just like any regular download popup: Open, Save, Save As. Any idea?

---

In order to overcome “Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made” exception, Threading had to be implemented, see EDIT!

EDIT:

1)

```
 using System.Threading;
```

2)

```
[STAThread]
private static void ExportToExcel(DataTable dt)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(SaveIt);
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start(dt);
}
```

3)

```
static void SaveIt(Object dt)
{
    DataTable table = (DataTable)dt;
    System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog sfd = new System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog();

    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        SaveName = sfd.FileName;
    else
        SaveName = "ResourceProfile";
    workbook.SaveAs(.....
}
```

END OF EDIT.

```
private static void ExportToExcel(DataTable dt)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(true);

    int iCol = 0;
    foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
    {
        iCol++;
        excel.Cells[1, iCol] = c.ColumnName;
    }

    int iRow = 0;
    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
        iRow++;

        // add each row's cell data...
        iCol = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
        {
             iCol++;
             excel.Cells[iRow + 1, iCol] = r[c.ColumnName];
        }
    }

    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;          

    String CurDate = CurrentDate.ToShortDateString().Replace("/",".");

    workbook.SaveAs("ResourceProfile-" + CurDate + ".xls", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet, missing, missing, false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);

    excel.Visible = true;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;
    ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)worksheet).Activate();

    ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application)excel).Quit();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z.aspx) to your application, and get the file name from the user:

```
String SaveName;

if saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog  = DialogResult.OK 
{
  SaveName := saveFileDialog1.FileName;
  workBook.SaveAs(SaveName, ...);
}
```

You can configure the default folder location, file extension, and other information by setting various properties of the `SaveFileDialog`. You can even set the `SaveDialog.FileName` to the default name you've created above before you `ShowDialog` for them to accept or modify.

You can also do it using `excel.Application.get_FileDialog` - here's an example:

```
Microsoft.Office.Core.FileDialog fd = 
  excel.Application.get_FileDialog(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoFileDialogType.msoFileDialogSaveAs);

fd.AllowMultiSelect = true; 
fd.Filters.Clear(); 
fd.Filters.Add("Excel Files", "*.xls;*.xlw", missing); 
fd.Filters.Add("All Files", "*.*", missing); 

if (fd.Show() != 0)
{
  fd.Execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ken, I have added SFD and now receiving the following error as soon as it reached "sfd.ShowDialog()": Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process.  Does it ring any bells ?

Comment: Not really; the code usually works fine. Are you doing your processing in a background thread? According to the error message, you can add the `STAThreadAttribute` to your `Main` function; it may have something to do with the debugger being the actual process running your app, since it's only raised under the debugger. Sorry I don't know the answer for that issue. Does my second code segment (using Excel's own dialog) change anything?

Comment: Could it have anything to do with Ajax whatsoever ? I'm about to look into the other solution of yours.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. :( I don't do a lot of work with Excel automation any more; I usually work in Delphi, and have a third-party library that lets me write .xls files (complete with formatting, formulas, auto column sizing, etc.) without Excel running. (In fact, Excel doesn't even have to be installed.) The first code was just generic SaveAsDialog code, and the second I got from a quick check of [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.filedialog%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a ton Ken, there must be a way to make the first one work. I'll give it another half an hour, then post my findings.

Comment: @Jake, [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/2411f889-8e30-4a6d-9e28-8a46e66c0fdb/) should help solve your STA issue.

Comment: Sorted, it wasn't that hard on the end. Cheers Ken

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing "foreach" loop will take so much time if you are handling large number of records(lets say more then 20000 or more).

I would suggest to use EPPlus lib.

Here is how you can directly put datatable into excel:

```
worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dtForExcel, true);
```

I have tested it and its just taking approx 2Sec.

**I do not understand why MS has not given such facility in "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" ?**

Answer (score 0):

Use below mentioned code for displaying saveAs dialogue box in aspx.

```
        var excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        var workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(true);
        // to add a sheet to workbook
        AddExcelSheet(dataTable1, workbook, "Sheet Name");

        string spreadsheetName = "DefaultFilename";
        excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
        Dialog saveAsDialog = excel.Dialogs[XlBuiltInDialog.xlDialogSaveAs];

        // to show dialog box with default filename
        saveAsDialog.Show(spreadsheetName);

        workbook.Close(true);
        excel.Quit();
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
```